# Query [large] data records from Proficy Historian?

Tags: python, win32com, historian, proficy

I'm using the Proficy Historian SDK with python27. I can create a data record object and add the query criteria attributes (sample type, start time, end time, sample interval - in milliseconds) and use datarecord.QueryRecordset() to execute a query.

The problem I'm facing is that method QueryRecordset seems to only work for returning a small number of data sets (a few hundred records at most) i.e. a small date range, otherwise it returns no results for any of the SCADA tags. I can sometimes get it to return more (a few thousand) records by slowly incriminating the date range, but it seems unreliable. So, is there a way to fix this or a different way to do the query or set it up? Most of my queries contain multiple tags. Otherwise, I guess I'll just have to successively execute the query/slide the date range and pull a few hundred records at a time.

**Update:**
I'm preforming the query using the following steps:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants as c
import datetime

ihApp = EnsureDispatch('iHistorian_SDK.Server')
drecord = ihApp.Data.NewRecordset()
drecord.Criteria.Tags = ['Tag_1', 'Tag_2', 'Tag_3']
drecord.Criteria.SamplingMode = c.Calculated
drecord.Criteria.CalculationMode = c.Average
drecord.Criteria.Direction = c.Forward
drecord.Criteria.NumberOfSamples = 0 # This is the default value
drecord.Criteria.SamplingInterval = 30*60*1000 # 30 min interval in ms
# I've tried using the win32com pytime type instead of datetime, but it
# doesn't make a difference
drecord.Criteria.StartTime = datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 1)
drecord.Criteria.EndTime = datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 10)

# Run the query
drecord.Fields.Clear()
drecord.Fields.AllFields()
drecord.QueryRecordset()
```

One problem that may be happening is the use of dates/times in the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format. When I create a pytime or datetime object the individual attributes e.g. year, day, month, hour, minute are all correct before and after assignment to drecord.Criteria.StartTime and drecord.Criteria.EndTime, but when I print the variable it always comes out in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format, but this is probably due to the object's **str** or **repr** method.

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about, but anyway, good question.

Comment: I'll add some code tomorrow when I'm back at work. In the meantime my question is along the lines of extending what what is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306642/how-do-i-query-raw-data-from-a-proficy-historian/3320405#3320405)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out there were two properties that could be adjusted to increase the number of samples returned and time before a timeout occurred. Both properties are set on the server object (ihApp):

```
ihApp.MaximumQueryIntervals = MaximumQueryIntervals # Default is 50000
ihApp.MaximumQueryTime = MaximumQueryTime # Default is 60 (seconds)
```

Increasing both these values seemed to fix my problems. Some tags definitely seem to take longer to query than others (over the same time period and same sampling method), so increasing the max. query time helped make returning query data more reliable.

When QueryRecordset() completes it returns False if there was an error and doesn't populate any of the data records. The error type can be show using:

```
drecord.LastError
```